# error TS2345: Argument of type '(response: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: {}) => void | PromiseLike<void>) | null

Tags: typescript

I updated my typescript packages via npm and now I'm getting the error:

"TS2345: Argument of type '(response: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: {}) => void | PromiseLike) | null | undefined'"

when trying to compile the following code:

```
private _send<T>(urlPath: string, params?: RequestParams): Promise<T> {
    return this._requester.sendRequest<T>(this._datafeedURL, urlPath, params);
}

public getServerTime(callback: ServerTimeCallback): void {
    this._send('time')
        .then((response: string) => {
            const time = parseInt(response);
            if (!isNaN(time)) {
                callback(time);
            }
        })
        .catch((error?: string | Error) => {
            logMessage(`Failed to load server time, error=${getErrorMessage(error)}`);
        });
}
```

The error is coming from the .then line

I've read other similar questions but I can't make sense of the issue for my case.

Comment: Can you show us the `_send` method body? Or at least what its return type is?

Comment: Thanks, but now we need to go deeper. Typescript is failing to infer the type of `T`, so it's getting a default type of `{}` (which is too broad, causing the issue you're seeing). To see why that inference isn't working, we need to know the signature of `this._requester.sendRequest`. What is the type of `this._requester`, and if possible, can you post the code for its `sendRequest` method? Or if it's from a library, can you tell us which?

Comment: It really looks like you should say `this._send<string>('time')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature

```
_send<T>(urlPath: string, params?: RequestParams): Promise<T>;
```

takes returns a [`Promise<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1308-L1326), which has a `then()` method whose first argument is a callback taking a parameter of type `T`.  If you don't know what [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) are, you should read about them.  The five-second explanation is that a `Promise<Foo>` is an object that will eventually hold a `Foo` object at some point in the future, and you tell it (with the `then()` method) what it should do with that `Foo` object when it finally gets it.

Since you are calling `then()` with a callback function whose parameter is a `string`, you need `T` to be assignable to `string`.  The easiest way for this to happen is if `T` *is* `string`.

So what do you have to do with `_send()` to get `T` to equal `string`?  Notice that neither `urlPath` nor `params` depend on `T`.  That means there's almost no way for the compiler to infer any value for `T`.  And it looks like it's defaulting to the empty object type `{}`, which tends to happen when TypeScript can't infer any value for a type parameter.  Type argument inference (see [the Handbook section on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and look for "type argument inference" for more info) is not going to happen.

You are left with explicitly specifying the type parameter, by calling

```
this._send<string>('time')
```

This should allow your `then` call to compile successfully.  Beware that by explicitly setting the type parameter `T` to `string` you are trusting that the asynchronous call will actually return a `string` at runtime.  The signature of `_send()` does seemingly guarantee that it will return a `Promise<T>` for *any* value of `T` that the caller specifies, but obviously it cannot really do that at runtime.  So be careful.

Hope that's of some help.  Good luck!